# Not being able to render into FBO with Depth Attachment

Tags: java, opengl, 3d, shader, lwjgl

I am trying to implement shadow mapping for a few days now and I think I am starting to see the real issue at hand: I have an FBO with a Depth Texture attached to it, for the light pass of shadow mapping, however nothing is being rendered in it. Not even hardcoded values.

I have double checked the part of the program that visualizes the depth texture, and that is working with regular textures, moreover I see no shadows appearing in my scene, so I think something is definately wrong.

init:

```
    //shadow FBO and texture
    depthFBO = new FrameBufferObject().create().bind();
    depthTexture = new Texture2D().create().bind()
            .storage2D(12, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT32F, 4096, 4096)
            .minFilter(GL_LINEAR)
            .magFilter(GL_LINEAR)
            .compareMode(GL_COMPARE_REF_TO_TEXTURE)
            .compareFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
    depthFBO.texture2D(GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, depthTexture, 0)
            .checkStatus().unbind();
    depthTexture.unbind();
```

render:

```
    depthFBO.bind();
    glViewport(0, 0, 4096, 4096);
    glEnable(GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_FILL);
    glPolygonOffset(4.0f, 4.0f);
    glDrawBuffer(GL_NONE);
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glClearDepthf(1f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    Drawable.drawAllLightPass(drawables, lightNormalProgram, lightTessellationProgram);
    glDisable(GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_FILL);
    depthFBO.unbind();
```

Code in direct `gl*` calls.

init:

```
int frameBufferObjectId = GL30.glGenFramebuffers();
GL30.glBindFramebuffer(GL30.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, frameBufferObjectId);

int textureId = GL11.glGenTextures();
GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId);
GL42.glTexStorage2D(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 12, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT32F, 4096, 4096);
GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL14.GL_TEXTURE_COMPARE_MODE, GL_COMPARE_REF_TO_TEXTURE);
GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL14.GL_TEXTURE_COMPARE_FUNC, GL_LEQUAL);

GL30.glFramebufferTexture2D(GL30.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId, 0);
if (GL30.glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL30.GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL30.GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
    throw new RuntimeException(this + " is not complete.");
}
GL30.glBindFramebuffer(GL30.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
```

render:

```
GL30.glBindFramebuffer(GL30.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, frameBufferObjectId);
glViewport(0, 0, 4096, 4096);
glEnable(GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_FILL);
glPolygonOffset(4.0f, 4.0f);
glDrawBuffer(GL_NONE);
glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
glClearDepthf(1f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

//appropiate calls to glDraw* are being done, this is confirmed to work as it works for displaying data

glDisable(GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_FILL);
GL30.glBindFramebuffer(GL30.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
```

Now the most important shaders:

`light-normal.vs.glsl`

```
#version 430 core

layout(location = 4) uniform mat4 light_model_matrix;
layout(location = 5) uniform mat4 light_view_matrix;
layout(location = 6) uniform mat4 light_projection_matrix;

layout(location = 0) in vec4 position;

void main(void) {
    gl_Position = light_projection_matrix * light_view_matrix * light_model_matrix * position;
}
```

`light-normal.fs.glsl`

```
#version 430 core

layout(location = 0) out float depth;

void main(void) {
    depth = gl_FragCoord.z;
}
```

Also even hardcoding `depth` to either `0.0f`, `0.5f` or `1.0f` neither work.

Just to clarify if my expectations are correct: When I move my camera close to an object that is being rendered on the screen, then the color of the depth buffer should change? As depth will be close to 0.0f then, and far away from 1.0f?

Also another clarification: What I see as the depth-values, is a rectangle that is colored white everywhere.

As per request, shaders to visualize the depth texture data:

`depth-box.vs.glsl`

```
#version 430 core

void main(void) {
    const vec4 vertices[6] = vec4[](
        vec4(-1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0),
        vec4(-1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0),
        vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0),

        vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0),
        vec4(1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0),
        vec4(-1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
    ); 

    gl_Position = vertices[gl_VertexID];
}
```

`depth-box.fs.glsl`

```
#version 430 core

layout(location = 7) uniform int screen_width;
layout(location = 8) uniform int screen_height;

layout(binding = 0) uniform sampler2D shadow_tex;

out vec4 color;

void main(void) {
    vec2 tex_coords = vec2(
        (gl_FragCoord.x - 100) / (screen_width / 5),
        (gl_FragCoord.y - (screen_height - (screen_height / 5) - 100)) / (screen_height / 5)
    );
    color = vec4(vec3(texture(shadow_tex, tex_coords).r), 1.0);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not going to work, you forgot to disable texture comparison. You cannot sample a texture with a texutre comparison mode other than `GL_NONE` using `sampler2D`. ***The results will be undefined.***

`sampler2DShadow` is necessary to read a texture with comparison enabled. And when you do this, the first two texture coordinates work as normal but the third is the depth value to compare against and the return of `texture (...)` is a floating-point value (1.0 for pass, 0.0 for fail). It can be somewhere inbetween if you have a linear filter.

Comment: Updated it, and unfortunately it still does not work. When using `sampler2D` with `GL_NONE`.

Comment: Also confirmed by changing `glClearDepthf(1f);` in the `render` to for example `0.5f` that it does do something (namely becomes gray), so nothing gets drawn into the texture?

Comment: As for outputting `depth` in your shader, that is absolutely pointless. I am beginning to hate the book you got these shaders from. You are writing your window-space depth to a color buffer, but you have `glDrawBuffers (GL_NONE)`. Your shader should not even have an output called `depth`, remove that for your own good and use an empty fragment shader for the shadow map creation.

Comment: If you actually want something written in the fragment shader to affect the depth, you would write `gl_FragDepth`. However, ***do not do this*** for anything more than debugging because the rasterizer already generates this value and if you override it you will forfeit several hardware optimizations.

Comment: So, to sum that comment up, writing an empty shader is better such that the driver/hardware can optimize, and to provide consistency? And yeah, I'm not liking the book that much anymore either, however explanation on the net is even harder to come by.

Comment: Well, there are two reasons you want an empty shader. First of all, you have no FBO color attachment and the only thing that you can output to something like `out float depth` is actually a ***color buffer***. The depth buffer is *only* accessed through `gl_FragDepth`, but there is something even more important, and that is that the rasterizer generates the value stored in the depth buffer before the fragment shader runs (which is effectively the same thing as `gl_FragCoord.z`). If you avoid writing your own value in the fragment shader, hardware can do depth tests *before* running shaders.

Comment: That makes sense indeed, thanks for clarifying that. Where did you learn so much, some specific books/resources? Or just personal experience?

Comment: I have 15+ years of experience with OpenGL and computer graphics, its hard to say where exactly I picked up all these details. When I started out shaders did not even exist, so I have had many many years to learn the nuances of the hardware ;) Anyway, did writing a value to `gl_FragDepth` (again, only do this as a debug technique) change anything in your depth texture? If not, then you can conclude that something is wrong with the code that is drawing into the depth buffer attachment.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help, I think my next thing to tackle are the light Model, View and Projection matrices. Because I think that is literally the only other thing now that could go wrong.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46786/discussion-between-skiwi-and-andon-m-coleman)